# Retrieve random documents from collection

Tags: .net, mongodb

I have a filter like this

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(x => x.IsPublic, true);
 int skip = 0; int limit = 1000;
 var sort = Builders<Post>.Sort.Descending(x => x.Date);
 var posts = await postsRepository.QueryAsync(filter, skip, limit, sort);
```

Is it possible to use expand filter or sort in order to retrieve random posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) to retrieve random documents.